# Alternative To PictureBoxes?

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox

I want to make a game where you control a character in the middle of the screen and groups of enemies come towards you from all angles. In previous experiences I've found that having multiple picture boxes on the screen at the same time causes huge lag. I was wondering if anyone knew of a better way to have images on the screen which don't cause as much lag and that I can preferably control with the .top and .left expressions. Thanks!

Comment: You need to render to off-screen bitmaps and then render the final bitmap to the screen. You should be using DirectX for this kind of stuff, though - Winforms is not the best choice for games. There are several libraries that make DirectX easier to use from .Net.

Answer (score 0):

DirectX is faster and normally used for games.

If you prefer using PictureBox, use a single PictureBox. You can redraw the animated game figures in the PictureBox paint event, creating a GDI+ Graphics instance on a single picturebox, and use the picturebox's image for a persistent background.

Comment: GDI+ is spectacularly inefficient for any kind of graphics work. If the OP really wants to use a `PictureBox`, he should go with plain old GDI - it's an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: GDI+ is fast if you use 32bppPArgb bitmaps, and it can use simpler code. On the other hand, with old GDI is it possible to draw in XOR mode.